# Relationships between two objects in code first entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

So I have a Users class and a products class.

I am using Code first approach and trying to make it so that I can add in products and I can add in users and then have the relationship mapped between the two objects without having a foreign key relationship.

So in essence the user will have more than one product but the products will be defined.  I would do this normally in a database with a lookup table mapping the two of them but I can not for the life of me get Entity to do this functionality and am considering scrapping it and doing Database first design.

For the purposes of this question you can consider a user just a POCO with an ID and Products a POCO With an id.

I feel like I am dancing around this issue while searching but I can't find anything that solves it so sorry if the answer is out there already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is apparently the Fluent API framework.

you have to override this method in your context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
              HasMany(c => c.ActiveProducts).
              WithMany(p => p.UsersOfProduct).
              Map(
               m =>
               {
                   m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                   m.MapRightKey("ProductId");
                   m.ToTable("ProductUsers");
               });
        }
```

I still don't really get the whole "HasMany, WithMany" syntax of it all but this is what did it.  You have to do this so that it knows to create the relationship table and not just join the ID column onto the object by default.

Answer (score 1):

Object relationships depends on `Foreign Keys`, atleast that is how i know it should be. In your case, you are looking for `one-to-many` (That is one User with many Porducts).

Try this;

```
Public class User 
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int UserId { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

Public class Product
{
   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int ProductId{ get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("User"), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public int? UserId{ get; set; } 

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But I would like one user to have many products but only one product per... well product.  The way I would do this normally is two tables with primary keys and a lookup table that has the relationships.  That way I don't have to have many of the same product for each user.  So I think that is a many to many

Comment: Ok you helped me realize this was a many to many I appreciate it so much.  The answer I will provide.  THANK YOU!

Comment: @Roloc yes in that case you need a `many-to-many` relationship.